# Mirror modifier not applying shader on mirrored item

Tags: materials

I'm having an issue with mirror modifier on a characters eyes. I created a shader for a character eye but it does not carry over to the mirrored eye. The eye I created the shader on is the one on the right. I applied the mirror modifier, went in to edit mode and selected all the vertices for the left eye, separated it as a new object so, I have a left and right eye in the object tree. The shader also copied to the left eye but still won't activate. I'm thinking it's right in front of me as it has been awhile since I made eyes, maybe a switch I didn't throw. Now, here's another odd thing; when I click on each of the eyes, they both show the exact same location, even though you can see they are obviously separated from each other. That's a new one on me.

[image: Shader not taking]

Comment: Hey this could be because of the Texture coordinate Node. If you set it to UV and UV unwrap the eye it could fix the problem but im not sure. Can you share a blender file so i can check?

Comment: You are using _Object_ coordinate. If the original geometry for example sits at an X value of +1, the mirrored geometry is at -1. So the texture is set up to show a pupil at +1, but not at -1. To achieve this, one way would be to place a _Vector Math_ node set to _Absolute_ before the Gradient texture.

Comment: I was trying to keep everything procedural but I'm going to drop back and use an image for the pupil. Putting the Absolute Math node on it drove it crazy. I'll come back to it another time. Working at doing as much procedural to keep some processing time down and give a little more future modifying option there but the image won't be any big drain on processing

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to keep the sphere intact, a node should be able to cover it so, I tried putting the Absolute Math node in and it striped the thing but after manipulating the Mapping rotation and Y location awhile I was able to get the correct result. I did zero out the value in the Math node so all my adjusting was in the Mapping node.